# Orders of elements in a modular sum group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I found the following in my *"Sets, Relations and Groups"* textbook about the orders of the elements in the group $ G= (0,1,2,3,4) ,+_5 $:

$Ord(1) = 4$, which is the same for all other elements (except the identity, $e = 0$).

I was confused a bit because I know that, say element $1$, has an order of $5$ since $1^5 = 1+_51+_51+_51+_51 = 0 = e$.

Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the group $G_{+5}$? integer modulo $5$ with addition I suppose? Then yes, $1$ (and all other elements except $0$) have order $5$, not $4$.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks for pointing that out! feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: every non-identity element of $G$ has order $5$, not $4$.  I'm guessing you misinterpreted something the book said, or it was just a typo.